# MySql - Joins - Joining same table twice

Tags: mysql, sql, join

how can we achieve this with more efficiency when there are ton of records?

```
SELECT M.t1, M.t2,A.x2,B.x2
FROM M
JOIN  P as A ON A.x1 = M.t1
JOIN P as B ON B.x1 = M.t2;
```

please note, indexing has been applied already to M.t1 & M.t2.

Comment: update you question and add the indexes  you are using now

Answer (score 0):

If you have a "ton" of records, then your query is probably returning a "ton" -- or even more -- of records.  All you can do is add indexes.

For this query, I recommend an index on `P(x1, x2)`.  You might also find that an index on `M(t1)` works -- simply because the original data pages don't need to be read, only the index.